# Simple Javascript Behaviors

Tags: javascript

A long time ago I used to develop websites using Dreamweaver. But I am no longer using this software as I now code directly with a text editor (adapted to Ruby on Rail Framework )

Yet I am pretty bad with Javascript and was wondering if there was a solution that could help me replicate easily the Dreamweaver behaviors without getting deep into Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Dreamweaver Behaviours are tools to apply prewritten JavaScript functions (i.e. a library) with a GUI.

So find a JavaScript library that does what you want, and learn enough about JavaScript to write the code you need to apply it with your editor.

Comment: *"Dreamweaver Behaviours are just prewritten JavaScript functions"*. No it's not, it's written in C++. The OP's question is broad, they could be talking about any "Dreamweaver Behaviour".

Comment: Many thanks Quentin, I thought I could pass on Javascript but I think I will give it a try. I guess I can't really pass on it.